# consultar últimos dos dígitos mas repetidos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un campo con registro con números de 4 cifras, de esos números quiero saber los repetidos de los 2 últimos dígitos. Mostrando un "top 5"  mas repetidos esos números de dos cifras.
Espero haberme explicado correctamente.
Muchas gracias. Cualquier tipo de ayuda es bienvenida. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que fuiste bastante claro, entiendo que sería algo así:

```
SELECT TOP 5
       RIGHT(campo,2),
       COUNT(1)
       FROM Tabla
       GROUP BY RIGHT(campo,2)
       ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Comment: Muchas gracias realmente era lo que buscaba.